# GET from a Parse object failing

Tags: java, parse-platform

I'm trying to get values from Parse, but even after successfully PUT(ting) I can't seem to GET. The class is 'data' and the value is 'schoolOpen' (of type Boolean). What am I doing wrong? What I'm trying to do is get the Boolean value of schoolOpen (from Parse) and pass that into schoolOpenStatus.

```
package com.t99sdevelopment.centralized;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static boolean schoolOpenStatus = false;
    public static String testText = "It hasn't been changed.";
    ParseObject data = new ParseObject("data");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homescreen);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        setActionBarText("Home");

        parseInit();

        parseGet(null);

        TextView parseTestText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.parseTest);

        if (schoolOpenStatus == true){
            parseTestText.setText("IT'S OPEN");
        } else {
            parseTestText.setText("SNOW DAY WOOT");
        }

        System.out.print(schoolOpenStatus);
    }


    private void parseInit(){
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "epEwSw0NR98IbT5h0AlSpsqx0d43MvdxYPPdUIPP", "NvLTibN0IlZncqmzbIP0WYIpu3yNHzwIBS1klXiu");
        DataStore.isOpen = true;
    }

    public void parseGet(View view){
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("data");
        query.getInBackground("zF3GAgdbi3", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    schoolOpenStatus = data.getBoolean("schoolOpen");
                } else {
                    // something went wrong
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setActionBarText(String actionBarText){
        TextView actionBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        actionBar.setText(actionBarText);
    }

    public void goToHome(MenuItem item){}

    public void goToAnnouncements(MenuItem item){
        Intent intentAnnouncements = new Intent(this, AnnouncementsScreen.class);
        startActivity(intentAnnouncements);
    }

    public void goToSchedule(MenuItem item){
        Intent intentSchedule = new Intent(this, ScheduleScreen.class);
        startActivity(intentSchedule);
    }

    public void goToCalendar(MenuItem item){
        Intent intentCalendar = new Intent(this, CalendarScreen.class);
        startActivity(intentCalendar);
    }

    public void goToContactBook(MenuItem item){
        Intent intentContactBook = new Intent(this, ContactBookScreen.class);
        startActivity(intentContactBook);
    }

    public void goToFrontAndCentral(MenuItem item){
        Intent intentFrontAndCentral = new Intent(this, FrontAndCentralScreen.class);
        startActivity(intentFrontAndCentral);
    }

    public void goToMap(MenuItem item){
        Intent intentMap = new Intent(this, MapScreen.class);
        startActivity(intentMap);
    }

    public void goToAccount(MenuItem item){
        Intent intentAccount = new Intent(this, AccountScreen.class);
        startActivity(intentAccount);
    }
}
```

Also, the log continuously spits out:

```
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching `schoolOpen` from wrong `ParseObject`

```
 schoolOpenStatus = data.getBoolean("schoolOpen");
```

instead of use `done` response `ParseObject` which is `object`

```
 schoolOpenStatus = object.getBoolean("schoolOpen");
```